# PHPMailer Notice: Undefined variable

Tags: javascript, php, angular, phpmailer

I am sending an email from a form using PHPMailer and Angular, but I get an error log every time I send the data: PHP Notice: Undefined variable: name, email and message. Therefore, I get the mail in my email account, but it has no data from the form. My html inputs already have the attribute name.

My code is:

```
<?php

require 'PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

require 'includes/PHPMailer.php';
require 'includes/SMTP.php';
require 'includes/Exception.php';

use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;

if(isset($_POST['nombre']) && isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['mensaje'])){
    
    $nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $mensaje = $_POST['mensaje']; 
}

$mail = new PHPMailer(true);

    //Server settings

    $mail->SMTPDebug = SMTP::DEBUG_SERVER; 
    $mail->Host       = 'smtp.gmail.com';                     
    $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                                  
    $mail->Username   = 'kanazawa8213@gmail.com';
    $mail->Password   = '*****';                             
    $mail->SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_SMTPS;           
    $mail->Port       = 587;  

    //Recipients
    $mail->setFrom('kanazawa8213@gmail.com', 'Ptree');
    $mail->addAddress('kanazawa8213@gmail.com');     

    //Content
    $mail->isHTML(true);                                 
    $mail->Subject = 'Nuevo mensaje desde Ptree site';

    $mail->Body = "Este es un mensaje desde Ptree site:\n\n".
        " Nombre: ".$nombre.
        "\n\n Email: ".$email.
        "\n\n Mensaje: " .$mensaje;


if($mail->send()){
        echo 'Message has been sent';
    }else{
        echo 'Message could not be sent.';
        echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    }


?>
```

This is my Angular service, Does it lack something?

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, of, from } from 'rxjs';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { catchError, map, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { environment } from '../../environments/environment';

const httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type':'application/json'})
};

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class MycontactService {

  apiUrl = environment.apiUrl;
  emailUrl = environment.emailUrl;

  constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }

  private handleError<T>(operation = 'operation', result?: T) {
    return (error: any): Observable<T> => {
      console.error(error);
      console.log(`${operation} failed: ${error.message}`);
      return of(result as T);
    }
  }


  sendMessage(landingForm:any): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.post<any>(`${this.emailUrl}`, landingForm, httpOptions).pipe(
        tap(
            message => console.log(message)
        ),
        catchError(this.handleError('Sending', []))
    );
  }

}
```

Also I added my form.component.ts file

```
 import { Component, OnInit, AfterViewInit, ElementRef, Inject, PLATFORM_ID } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators, FormControl, NgForm  } from '@angular/forms';
import { isPlatformBrowser } from '@angular/common';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { MycontactService } from '../../services/mycontact.service';
import { AngularFirestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-form',
  templateUrl: './form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./form.component.scss']
})
export class FormComponent implements OnInit {


  landingForm!: FormGroup;
  public href: string = "";

  loading = false;
  buttonText = "Enviar";  

  showMsg: boolean = false;

  sending!: boolean;


  constructor(private el: ElementRef,
              private fb: FormBuilder,
          private http: HttpClient,
          private contactService: MycontactService,
              // public db: AngularFirestore,
              private router: Router,
              @Inject(PLATFORM_ID) private platformId: Object
            ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {

        this.href = this.router.url;
        console.log('Hola ' + this.href);

        this.landingForm = this.fb.group({
          opciones: ['', Validators.required],
          nombre: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern(/^([a-zA-Z ]|[à-ú]|[À-Ú])+$/)]],
          // email: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern(/^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/)]],
          email: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern(/^([\w-.]+@(?!gmail\.com)(?!yahoo\.com)(?!hotmail\.com)([\w-]+.)+[\w-]{2,})?$/)]],
          telefono: [null, Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.minLength(8), Validators.maxLength(13), Validators.pattern(/^[0-9 ]*$/)])],
          empresa: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(1), Validators.maxLength(50)]],
          mensaje: ['', [Validators.minLength(1), Validators.maxLength(250)]],
          empleados: ['', Validators.required],
          pais: ['', Validators.required],
          acceptTerms: ['', Validators.required],
        recaptcha: ['', Validators.required],
          timestamp: [''],
          // campana: ['home'],
          // version: ['1'],
          referrer: [this.router.url]
        });

      console.log(this.router.url);
      this.sending = false;
  }

  siteKey:string = "6LeSbRAcAAAAAGXmlbPS9AIyclXwT1YTT_mJ1i50";
 
  ngAfterViewInit() {   
  }



    onSubmit(landingForm:any){
      this.sending = true;
      console.log(landingForm);
      this.contactService.sendMessage(landingForm).subscribe(
        data => {
          console.log(data);
          this.showMsg = true;
          setTimeout( () => {                           // 
            this.showMsg = false;
          }, 3000);
        } 
      );


      
     
    }




}
```

Comment: Is that your actual account password...? Don't put that on the internet. Anyway, your code checks for the existence of the POST data but sends the email regardless. The problem isn't your PHP code, it's the angular (JS) line that makes the request. That's the code you need to show to us.

Comment: Wrap the rest of the code inside the if that you need to fire for the email to have the data you need. If it doesn't fire, you know that one of your post values aren't set.

Comment: Hello Chris G, I added my 'service.ts' file because I am using Angular 10

Comment: How are you calling `sendMessage` / what exactly is stored in `landingForm`? Did you inspect the POST request in the browser's dev tools and make sure it has the proper data?

Comment: Hello Chris, I have also added my form component ts file which has the onSubmit() function.  And, No, I have not inspected my Post request in my browser dev tools, I think I will, ja!

Comment: error: Object { error: SyntaxError, text: "Message has been sent" }

error: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data
​​
text: "Message has been sent"
​​
<prototype>: Object { … }
​
headers: Object { normalizedNames: Map(0), lazyUpdate: null, lazyInit: lazyInit()
 }
​
message: "Http failure during parsing for https://ptree.com.mx/api/index.php"
​
name: "HttpErrorResponse"
​
ok: false
​
status: 200
​
statusText: "OK"
​
url: "https://ptree.com.mx/api/index.php"

Comment: Try sending [`landingForm.value`](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup#usage-notes) instead

Comment: If my suggestion did work, consider removing the question; this will also remove the gmail password (which I can still see in the edit history) (also, in order to notify me, add `@ChrisG` to your comment)

Answer (score 1):

Delete this line as this file no longer exists in PHPMailer:

```
require 'PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
```

This line:

```
$mail->SMTPDebug = SMTP::DEBUG_SERVER;
```

will output debug information, which will corrupt the integrity of any JSON you're meant to be returning to the browser, and is likely the cause of your JSON parsing failure. Disable debug output by either deleting that line, or setting it to false.

```
$mail->SMTPDebug = false;
```

In general, to debug this kind of issue, you should be using your browser's inspector console to look at exactly what is coming back from your XHR requests – this debug output would be very obvious in there.

You're also asking PHPMailer to throw exceptions (by passing `true` to the constructor), but you are not using a try/catch block, so if the send fails, you will get a fatal unhandled exception and will never see your error output.